# How to update a Powerpoint slide with an external database?

Tags: microsoft-excel, mysql, microsoft-powerpoint, database

I have a database of 1000 users with their name, number, photos, addresses, and other fields, etc. (in RDBMS-like say mysql, PostgreSQL). But I want to implement this mostly in Excel.

So what I want is to create a single slide with all the empty fields for name, number, photos, address, etc. (as a template), then Powerpoint should automatically pick up data entries from the database and put it into the empty fields.

How can I implement that?

Any other alternavtives are acceptable.

Comment: What is the bigger picture? PowerPoint is for supporting a speaker giving a presentation. If you need a database, Powerpoint is not the right tool. If you want to give a presentation, automated slides are not a good idea. Give the audience a paper print-out with the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of non-free solutions:

http://www.take-off.as/solutions/automation.htm,

http://www.momsoftco.com/powermerge.htm*

... but if you don't want to open the chequebook you're either going to have to resort to vba, or maybe do the grunt work in Word - which has [database merging capabilities](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/word-help/about-mail-merge-fields-HP003082025.aspx), and then save to ppt(x).

*Disc. I work for neither of these nor do I vouch for their usefulness